# Android app APK fails to connect to web service

Tags: android, web-services, cordova, apk

Developed an Android app using HTML5, Javascript, Backbone and Phonegap. We can connect to the STAGING web service using both deployment methods: Eclipse to device deployment (Kindle) and APK.

With the same client code, we can connect to the PUBLIC web service using Eclipse to device deployment. But using the APK, we can’t connect to the public web service. The client code has not changed, only the staging and public web service URLs.

Checked Logcat, no errors. Eliminated possible Proguard issue, it is not enabled. Added debug console statements and the URL does not change after APK. Domain whitelisted,

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

Might be a server permission issue (filtering against user agent) but then it should have also failed with the Eclipse to device deployment.

Any ideas or additional suggestions for debugging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check access origin in config.xml

It should allow access to public webservice

`<access origin='*'  >`

Comment: Yes, it was already included. I forgot to include it in the description above.

Comment: Check if you can access webservice from localhost

Comment: Yes, I was able to connect from localhost

Comment: Is there any problem with internet connection of your device?

Comment: No, tried 2 devices and the internet connection works on both (not behind a firewall).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by fixing a bad SSL certificate.